# Hard refresh checks the authorization every time in React application

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, refresh

At the very beginning of the app, it checks authorization from tokens in localStorage.
So if a user closed and open a browser again, it checks authorization automatically if the token exists.
But, because of that, if a user does the refresh in any places/pages of the app, it checks authorization again and shows the login page. I do want the auto-check from browser opening, but do not want auto-check from a refresh. How can I handle this?

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     dispatch(action.checkAuth());
>   }, [dispatch]);
>
>   return (
>     <ConnectedRouter>
>       <Switch>
>         <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
>         <RestrictedRoute
>           path=""
>           component={Main}
>           isLoggedIn={idToken}
>         />
>       </Switch>
>     </ConnectedRouter>
>   );
> ```

Saga `checkAuth` function is here:

> ```
> export function* checkAuth() {
>   yield takeEvery(actions.CHECK_AUTH, function* ({ token }) {
>       const userRes = yield call(
>         fetch,
>         apiPrefix + "/user?token=" + token
>       );
>
>       if (userRes === "200") {
>         yield put({
>           type: actions.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
>           profile: userRes,
>           isLoading: false,
>         });
>
>         yield put(push("/"));
>       }
>     } else {
>       yield put({
>         type: actions.LOGIN_ERROR,
>         msg: "User does not exist.",
>         isLoading: false,
>       });
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
useEffect(() => {
if(!localStorage.getItem("token")){
dispatch(action.checkAuth());
}}, [dispatch]);
```

Now this will work .